# Multiwindow does not work with Youtube

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-7.0-nougat

When using Multiwindow on Android N, the `onPause()` is called when touching the other window, causing the youtube player to pause. As specified by the [Multiwindow Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#lifecycle) the video should be pausing in the `onStop()`. Is there any way I can make this happen on my own, or do I need to wait for the API to update?

Comment: Can we see some code which your are trying?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the YouTube Player API, can you file a bug on the [Android N Issue Tracker](http://developer.android.com/preview/bug)? Preferably with a small sample project.